# Filter Traffic Between Virtual Machines

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, virtualization

I have a machine with Fedora 21 which acts as a host system for two virtual machines. The VMs are made up using QEMU/KVM/libvirt/virt-manager. One VM is running a webserver, the other VM acts as a client. The client can visit the server so networking works well so far. I think it is somehow managed via the virbr0 interface on the host machine which also acts as the default gateway for the VMs.

Now, on the host machine, I want to filter the network traffic of the virtual machines. For example I want to put it in a netfilter queue and accept or drop it depending on certain circumstances. An exemplary iptables rule is `iptables -I FORWARD -i virbr0 -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 1`

In general it seems to work because when I drop every packet coming into the queue, the VMs are no longer able to visit websites on the Internet. Of course not, the default gateway drops the packets. Fine so far.

But I can't stop the traffic between the two VMs. Even if I drop the packets, the Client is able to load the page offered by the webserver VM. I think this is because the virtualization forms a network where the two VMs are connected w/o the need of a default gateway.

So can someone tell me how to control the traffic between two VMs via iptables and netfilter queue?

And I want to do the filter work on the host machine only. And blocking the whole traffic is not intended. It's only about filtering in certain circumstances. Therefore the netfilter queue.

Comment: The fwmark mechanism is what you need to use to make selectable traffic. Its late but by reading up on marking packets and then making rule chains related to that you should be able to accomplish what you want. Also having them on separate bridges will enable filtering.

Comment: Thanks. fwmark seems inappropriate for me because I need to process the packets in userspace during filtering. So I still need something like netfilter queue. But having them on separate bridged sounds good. Probably I need a more comprehensive answer how I could configure this such that one VM uses virbr0 and the other uses virbr1 (which is not existent at the moment).